# How to iterate Guava multimap in thymleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, guava

I have below map collection. I want to iterate this in thymeleaf but getting below error.

```
Multimap<String,String> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();

<div th:each="m : ${menu.entries}">
```

EL1008E: Property or field 'entries' cannot be found on object of type 'com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap' - maybe not public or not valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of iterating a Guava multimap in Thymeleaf.

Some test data:

```
Multimap<String, String> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
map.put("key one", "value one");
map.put("key two", "value two a");
map.put("key two", "value two b");
map.put("key three", "value three");
```

The Thymeleaf:

```
<div th:each="k : ${menu.keySet()}">
    <div th:text="'key is: ' + ${k}">
    </div>
    <div th:each="v : ${menu.get(k)}">
        <div th:text="'val is: ' + ${v}">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This gives the following output in the web page (ordering is not guaranteed):

```
key is: key two
val is: value two a
val is: value two b
key is: key one
val is: value one
key is: key three
val is: value three
```